# setPropertyActionListener not fired the setter method of target

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

`<f:setPropertyActionListener>` does not call the setter method of target object when I have the `<h:inputText>` in the JSF page but it triggered properly when I interchange h:inputText  with `<h:outputText>` and the values are loading properly. I am amused with the behavior of `<h:inputText>`. Here is the code

index.xhtml

```
<p:row>
    <p:column><p:outputLabel value="ID"/></p:column>
    <p:column ><h:inputText  value="#{bean.obj.innerObj.id}"/></p:column>
</p:row>

<p:commandButton update=":form:detail" 
                 oncomplete="PF('dialog').show()"
                 icon="ui-icon-search"
                 title="View">

    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{detail}"
                                 target="#{bean.obj}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Bean.java

```
public Obj getObj() {
    return obj;
}

public void setObj(Obj pObj) {
   this.obj = pObj;
}
```

I don't believe there is an issue with Bean.java as the setter method was called when I have `<h:outputText>` in index.xhtml.

Comment: Are there getters and setters for `#{itemsBean.selectedItemDetail}`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [commandLink/commandButton/ajax backing bean action/listener method not invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked)

Comment: Yes, that's a problem in my edit, actually the selectedItemDetail is represented as obj

Comment: What is `detail` supposed to be?